# Use webengine video and audio codecs

Tags: python, pyqt, pip, pyqt5, qtwebengine

For my PyQt5 project, I am using the `QWebEngineView`, but certain videos, such as `.mp4` videos won't play. Can I install the codecs with `pip`, or pass a certain argument through `QApplication()` or something similar in order to fix this problem?

I installed PyQt5 through `pip`, so I don't have the `C:\Qt\...` files, only the `PyQt5`, `pyqt5_tools` folders in `Appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages`.

I am using `Python 3.7.2`, and `PyQt5.11`

Comment: pip has nothing to do with this. Neither does python. This is a question of the Qt Multimedia Framework. You should research how that integrates with codecs. I presume it will delegate to the OS for codec support, and that's where you must install them. Not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pyqtwebengine provided by pypi does not enable the `use_proprietary_codecs` flag so you cannot play the .mp4.

If you want to get a pyqtwebengine that plays mp4 you must follow these steps:

1. You must compile Qt with the `WEBENGINE_CONFIG += use_proprietary_codecs` flag to enable the codecs needed to play mp4([Qt WebEngine Features: Audio and Video Codecs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#audio-and-video-codecs))
2. Then using that Qt you must compile pyqtwebengine.

Comment: How do I compile QT from the PyQt5 module folder?

Comment: @SamG101 Have you already compiled Qt5 with the flag that points to you?

Comment: All I have done is pip installed PyQt5 and pyqt5_tools, and then I'm importing them into Python (with from PyQt5.QtGui import * etc...)

Comment: @SamG101 As I pointed out that pyqt5 will not work for you since it is not compiled with the option that I indicated in my answer. If you have never compiled Qt/PyQt manually then you will have to learn how to do it which can take a long time.

Comment: Once I've built the new webengine, can I simply place it in the PyQt5 folder in place of the original webengine exe??

Comment: @SamG101 It seems so, I have tried it on Linux and it works correctly.

Comment: Don't suppose in the interveening years a half decent manual for building pyqtwebengine has appeared?